# How to make repeater element scrollable?

Tags: asp.net

I have this repeater asp element:

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="PervousResultsList" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" >
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="row1">
                <table style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td rowspan="4" onclick="parent.parent.ZoomToView(<%# Eval("Lon") %>, <%# Eval("Lat") %>, 2500)" style="cursor: pointer;">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl="~/Images/pushpinred.png" runat="server" Width="32"
                                Height="32" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td rowspan="10">
                            <asp:Image class="toggleRow" ImageUrl="~/Images/vertical-dots.png" runat="server" Width="32"
                                Height="32" Style="height: 30px; position: relative; float: left; cursor: pointer;" /></td>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="pointDescArea">
                        <td>text:</td>
                        <td rowspan="2">
                            <h1 style="color: gray"><%# Eval("Text") %></h1>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="hidden">
                        <td>X:</td>
                        <td><%# Eval("Lon") %></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="hidden">
                        <td>Y:</td>
                        <td><%# Eval("Lat") %></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>

        <AlternatingItemTemplate>
            <div class="row2">
                <table style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td rowspan="4" onclick="parent.parent.ZoomToView(<%# Eval("Lon") %>, <%# Eval("Lat") %>, 2500)" style="cursor: pointer;">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl="~/Images/pushpinred.png" runat="server" Width="32"
                                Height="32" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td rowspan="10">
                            <asp:Image class="toggleRow" ImageUrl="~/Images/vertical-dots.png" runat="server" Width="32"
                                Height="32" Style="height: 30px; position: relative; float: left; cursor: pointer;" /></td>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="pointDescArea">
                        <td>טקסט:</td>
                        <td rowspan="2">
                            <h1 style="color: gray"><%# Eval("Text") %></h1>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="hidden">
                        <td>X:</td>
                        <td><%# Eval("Lon") %></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="hidden">
                        <td>Y:</td>
                        <td><%# Eval("Lat") %></td>
                    </tr>
                  </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </AlternatingItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

I need to set it's height to 500px and make scrollable.

How can I make this repeater scrollable vertically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the repeater inside a `div`, set the div's height and use `overflow-y`

```
<div style="height: 500px; overflow-y: scroll;">
    <asp:Repeater ID="PervousResultsList" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" >
    ...
    </asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

Ideally the styling should be in `style` tags or in a stylesheet, but I'm showing it inline just for demonstration.

Comment: Any idea can I make height dynamic with maximum height?

Comment: Sure.  You could change the `height` property on the outer div to `max-height` if you only want the repeater to take up 500px if needed.  Also, if you only wanted the scrollbars to show when the max height is reached, you could set `overflow-y` to `auto`.